# how can stop change photo in html

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I want to help to make this code execution stops after just three times for?

I have three photos and want to change for three times and stop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "image1.jpg";
          images[1] = "image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "image3.jpg";
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="1.jpg"/>
       <button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

can you help me?

Comment: Try to add (all) relevant tags when asking a question; that way, a lot more people will be able to reach -and thus try and help- you. HTML isn't really what this question is about, it should be javascript. Good luck!

Comment: You have to use `clearInterval` method, refer [w3schools.com Window clearInterval() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`clearInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) to stop the `setInteval` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>change picture</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      var interval = 0;
      var counter = 0;
      
      function displayNextImage() {
        x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        if (counter == 3) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
        x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
        document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
      }

      function startTimer() {
        interval = setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qVbB.jpg";
      images[1] = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4D6Z.jpg";
      images[2] = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbyGx.jpg";
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload = "startTimer()">
    <img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qVbB.jpg"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this answer your question?

Comment: I'm happy to hear :) Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) the answer so it will help to other people.